# displaying a scraped url with accented characters

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

If I'm scraping the url of a website with an accented character such as é in it, what's the best way to store it in my mysql database so that when it is retrieved and displayed on screen it shows é instead of %C3%A9

I'm using utf8.  When I scrape actual web data it is stored in my database as Ã© and it displays fine, it's only when I'm scraping urls that I have issues.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: If it stores as "Ã©" it's wrong. Fix your UTF-8 workflow first with the aforelinked duplicate. Secondly, you need to *urldecode* "%C3%A9".

Comment: Also, if it stores as "Ã©" you're not using UTF-8, you're using ISO-8859-1 (at least in your database).

Comment: Thanks guys, urldecode worked perfectly for me.